# How to read small portion of a 10 GB csv file in D3.js

Tags: csv, d3.js, treemap

I am using D3.js to visualize a treemap. The data for the treemap is saved in a csv file which is 10 GB. It is too large to read all lines into the memory. Are there any way to read certain portion of the lines, draw the treemap a bit and then come back to read the remaining csv file again?

Comment: No, you'll have to split up the file.

Comment: Not with D3 directly. You could set up a websocket between the client and the server and retrieve the data incrementally through it.